# Selenium python cant find div innerText

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

i wanna load with a selenium python bot periodically new messages of a website.
the messages come in div's with innerText.

here is the part of my skript checking with xPath:
`
try:
while True:
messages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'text-message')]")
for message in messages:
print(message.text)
time.sleep(5)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("Stopped by user")
`

in the console i can test the xpath and it returns an array of div's with all messages.

the structure of the website: [image: web structure]

i tried so many stuff but cant get the messages. ChatGPT is also no help at all.

anyone can help me?

Thanks!!

changing the xPath, searching by class, using an observer, ExpectedConditions, ...

Comment: "in the console i can test the xpath and it returns an array of div's with all messages." ? so you can or cant get the messages?

Comment: probabily the Pyhton script see another page. Does the website has some sort of protection against webscraping/bot?

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius i get the messages in the console. my search: $x("//div[contains(@class, 'text-message') and contains(@class, 'pink') and contains(@class, 'accent-2')]")

Comment: @NicoCaldo oh my... i have to check. it changes the tab. i didnt thought of that :0 I will get back in a minute

Comment: @ToniBarsties got a similar problem with one of my site under cloudflare that was detecting my Python script as bad bot. Try to print a screenshot of the page the script sees

Comment: @NicoCaldo i forgot the tab change. sometimes its so simple but you cant see it :facepalm: Thanks for your message :)

Comment: feel free to accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Probabily Selenium is seeing a different page for some reason.

I would try to check what it's seeing with a screenshot

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = ‘path\to\chromedriver.exe’’)
url = "my_website_url"’
driver.get(url)
driver.save_screenshot(‘ss.png’)
screenshot = Image.open(‘ss.png’)
screenshot.show()
```

Maybe it's blocked by some security features and/or you're on another tab/page